# identify data uniquely in a array in mongo db collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, database

I have to collections namely **birthday** and **contact**
the db models of both of them are given below . What i am trying to achieve is a user can have many contacts and all those contacts have birthdays , as the user is saving the data in db , i am checking for their birthday and saving in second collection , but when the number of contact in contacts array is more than one , how will i identify uniquely the birth of that user
contact model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', {
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    contacts: [
        {
            "firstName": String,

            "birthday": {
                "date": Number,
                "month": Number,
                "year": Number
            }

        }
    ]
});
```

birthday model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('ContactBirthday', {
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    birthday: {
        "date": [
            {
                "firstName": String,
                 "date" : String
                "uniqueId": String //to identify contacts uniquely
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Here is what i need , when a user adds his contact , i need to save his birthday in different collection too , for the first contact in array i can just use the contact[0] even for the add contact i can use contact[contact.length-1] , but when user edits a specific contact , how will i identify that contact and his birthday in both collections, more like  a join
Thanks

Comment: Simplify to problem please, too much unnecessary code parts

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly simplified a bit :)